# Debug rest class that sits in a site

Tags: apex, rest-api, apexrest, debugging, winter17

I am having a lot of trouble debugging this type of class that is currently siting in a site.

The REST method works fine, but I just cant get it to log each time it is used.

I have already add the user in the logs, and I know it works fine as when I open a page from that site (after setting up the cookie) the logs display, but not for the rest class.

Is there any new set up that I need to get this working?

Comment: Alternate workaround solution: instead of debug statements, use a string array and use a dml insert to a Log__c object with a text area long 128K field.  Do the insert at the end of the REST transaction

Comment: If you know the payload, use the dev console to call the method directly and then you will be able to get debug logs. How are your hitting the REST endpoint? It is typical not in a site, rather requires authentication. Otherwise its just another class. Do you get debug logs from the VF controller class for a site guest user

Comment: Well I was getting debug logs as normal until a few months i think with winter release we now need to add a cookie in sites to be able to get the log going, so this was the end for my debuging of the class. On how I am hitting the rest I am using postman